# limiting values of edittext to certain values in android

Tags: android, xml, android-textwatcher

I am using edit text in my code.I need to limit the weight value to 160 .How to achieve this.

This is the XML I'm using

> ```
>    android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>                         android:inputType="number"
>                         android:layout_weight="0"
>                         android:background="@drawable/border"
>                         android:padding="5dp"
>                         android:maxLength="3"
>                         android:textSize="15sp"
>                         android:maxLines="1"
>                         android:hint=""
> ```

i have taken maxLenght as "3". So user will have option of entering upto 999 . I need to limit to 160.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
    try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
}
}
```

Then on your fragment / activity:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "180")});
```

Comment: Thank you!, plase mark it as the correct answer if it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
 InputFilter if = new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("0", "180")}
```

or customize it

```
InputFilter filterTwoDecimal = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            return null;

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextWatcher to your EditText and make changes to it so it won't allow unwanted values

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```